# autoLoad: false is ignored when used with grid filters

Tags: extjs

This bug has been reported here, but still present in ExtJS 7.

https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?305380-Store-autoLoad-false-is-ignored-if-remoteFilter-is-true-and-there-are-filters-in-Grid

In Summary:
When you use grid filters, the store attached with the grid is always auto loaded when the grid is rendered, even if you set the "autoLoad" property to false.

Does anybody know why they haven't fixed it yet? Any recommended workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: Just add the filter at the time, when you want to load the store the first time ;)

Comment: Btw, the workaround is stated in the forum. SO is not there for discussions like that. You need to contact idera / sencha. If you are a customer, feel free to contact the support. Poor performance by sencha / idera anyway.

Comment: @John Smith This issue seems to be resolved in the 7.5 release, [check here](https://www.sencha.com/blog/extjs-7-5-has-arrived/), see under Quality Improvements or [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.5.0/guides/whats_new/release_notes.html).

Comment: Yes! Finally has been solved.